# VS2008 (Windows CE) auto-resize dataGrid Column width

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am using Visual Studio 2008 for a Windows CE 6.0 application.
For that, I use a dataGrid-Control (not dataGridView!).
It gets it datasource at runtime as a List, that contains objects of this:

```
public class lastModified
{
    public int amount{ get; set; }
    public long coding{ get; set; }
}
```

That is working well, but the width of both columns is very small, and I can't find an option for the dataGrid to align it 100% to the window.
Is there a possibility to achieve that?

edit:

is there a way to rename the column-captions?

edit2:

I tried this:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3812/Resizing-Data-Grid-Columns-To-Content
```

which causes a "Invalid Cast Exception"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it:

```
        dgLatestPositions.DataSource = items;

        DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        tableStyle.MappingName = items.GetType().Name;

        // Column 1
        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcCoding= new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcCoding.Width = 100;
        tbcCoding.MappingName = "Coding";
        tbcCoding.HeaderText = "Coding";
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcCoding);

        // Column 2
        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcAmount = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcAmount .Width = 100;
        tbcAmount .MappingName = "Amount";
        tbcAmount .HeaderText = "Amount";
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcAmount );

        dgLatestPositions.TableStyles.Clear();
        dgLatestPositions.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);
```

Not autosize, but at least bigger.

Comment: In VB .. Other than items.GetType().Name .. this can all be achieved in table mappings within the DataGrid in Design view